# Downcasting in Rust: Where is the data for `self.type_id` being pulled from in the implementation of `is` for the `Error` trait?

Tags: rust

#### Rust Downcasting

I came to this question while trying to understand downcasting in Rust.

This is effectively the reverse operation of creating a Trait object from a reference (pointer, address of) a concrete type.

There is a nice diagram of how this is done in Section *Trait Objects* of Chapter 11 *Traits and Generics*, of Programming Rust, Second Edition. (O'Reilly) (pp 259)

While reading this, it occurred to me that I did not fully understand where the RTI (Run Time Information) "lives".

In other words, `&dyn Trait` is a Trait Object. That is a fat pointer, which is a pair of memory addresses. One address points to the data, one address points to a vtable which contains (pointers to) function implementations.

- From this, we have indirect, but not direct information about the type:
- We don't know explicitly what the type is of the object which lives at the address pointed to by the data pointer.
- But we know how to perform a set of operations on the data which we have a pointer to, because we have a pointer to some vtable which is a set of pointers to the relevant functions (operations).

The fat pointer is created at compile time. Rust creates it using the pointer from the concrete type (data) and inserts a pointer to the corresponding vtable.

As noted in the book

> You can't query the type information directly, and ***Rust does not support downcasting*** from the trait object `&mut dyn Write` back to a concrete type like `Vec<u8>`.

My interpretation of this is that the fat pointer does not contain any RTI about the type. That seems kind of obvious. It **could** have been implemented a number of ways: (But isn't.)

- The fat pointer could have contained RTI.
- The fat pointer points to the data, which could have contained RTI.
- The fat pointer points to a vtable for the type. The vtable could have contained RTI.

*Aside: By RTI here I mean some tag which can be used at runtime to figure out what the type is associated with the data being operated on. It could be as simple as a unique integer identifier. What this RTI would have permitted, should it have existed, would be a way for Rust to query the type of some data at runtime. That would permit downcasting, which is not something currently supported in the language. Languages like C++ do support downcasting. For dynamic languages like Python, it is an essential core feature, even more so than something like C++.*

From this I conclude that downcasting in Rust, which can be done using the `Any` and `Error` traits, is a sort of hacky-work around for this missing feature.

What I am interested to know is exactly how this is done.

As can be seen in the [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/error.rs.html#237) and [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.is) for the `Error` trait, downcasting is implemented using an `is<T>` method.

What I haven't been able to figure out is how exactly this is done. In particular, from the source: (Copied from `Error`, but it appears to be the same for `Any`)

```
let t = TypeId::of::<T>();

// Get `TypeId` of the type in the trait object (`self`).
let concrete = self.type_id(private::Internal);
```

I can *guess* as how the first line works, but I am unsure about the last line containing `self.type_id`. This is a function, but where does it come from?

What defines the `type_id` function? I would guess this is an interface trait from somewhere else?

The `Error` trait appears to inherit from the `Debug` and `Display` traits. But neither of these appear to define a `type_id` function.

---

#### Auxiliary:

Please note:

*I am not saying Rust is a bad language for not supporting downcasting as a core feature. (Please do not misinterpret the use of the phrase "hacky-workaround".) While I personally think this would be a good feature to have, this question is about how the code in `Error` and `Any` works, rather than being a discussion about the language itself.*

However, while on this point, if any core Rust developers happen to come across this question, here's some reasons why downcasting might be a good thing to support as a core language feature:

- It would solve the problem that `Error` and `Any` solved with a manual implementation
- It at least appears to be relatively straightforward to implement, with one of the 3 above described locations for the RTI
- Sometimes it is necessary to query the type in order to perform branching logic rather than providing a trait function implementation for every possible type. Examples include: Factory functions, where a dynamic object is taken as an argument and converted to another dynamic object which is returned. Error handling, where it is sometimes necessary to query the error type to decide if it is something that should be handled or ignored. This is something which is dependent on the level of call stack. Some errors are best handled at the level of `fn main()` while others can be handled at deeper levels of function call stack.

Comment: I guess that just add a method to the vtable that return the id. in 8 years of rust I never used dyn and advice to never use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[It is defined in the trait `Error` itself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.70.0/src/core/error.rs.html#95-100) (or [in `Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.70.0/src/core/any.rs.html#196)).

This caused it to be stored in the vtable, and so for `&dyn Any` we *do* store RTI, but only for it (or other traits that explicitly request it). This way, you don't pay the overhead of RTI for all traits, only when it is required.

Comment: Ok that's very interesting. Rather than me asking a separate question about this, although I am happy to do so, can you offer some explanation to how this is working? I notice that this function appears to be hidden in some way - what is that about?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant What do you mean by "hidden"?

Comment: `#[doc(hidden)]` or does that just mean hidden from documentation generation?

Comment: Ok it seem like `Error` uses the `type_id` implementation from `Any` and `Any` is using it from `std::intrinsics`. -> `intrinsics::type_id::<T>()`

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant It does mean hidden from documentation, and it is so for `Error` because it's internal: you're not supposed to implement it or call it. For `Any` it is public.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant No, both do that via `TypeId::of()` (which does call the intrinsic).

Comment: Why does the type passed to that function have to have `'static` lifetime? Or is this just a limitation due to it being used for an `Error` type? (`Any` has the same requirement actually.)

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Because `TypeId` is not able to differentiate lifetimes, and if we would allow non-`'static` downcasting it would be unsound.